# jQuery Validate on form that is destroyed/recreated with Knockout

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, jquery-validate, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a form that is within a jQuery UI dialog that is created and destroyed every time I open and close the dialog (as part of a knockout custom binding).  The problem is that jQuery validation works the first time the dialog opens, but then doesn't work if I close and then reopen the dialog.

Here is a simplified snippet of the form that is within the jQuery UI dialog:

```
<div id="product-panel" data-bind="dialog: { autoOpen: false, destroyOnClose: true }, showDialog: $parent.selectedProduct">
    <form data-bind="submit: saveMe" id="product-form" method="post">

        <label>
            Name
            <input type="text" id="productName" name="productName" data-bind="value: productName">
        </label>

        <button type="submit" class="button">save</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

I'd show the contents of ko.bindingHandlers.dialog too, but I don't think it is really associated with the problem.  The one thing to know about the dialog custom binding is that it configures the jQuery UI dialog to be destroyed whenever it is closed.

I use jQuery's on() method to rebind validate to the form whenever the dialog opens again:

```
$("body").on("dialogopen", "#product-panel", function(event) { 
    $('#product-form').validate({
        rules: {
            productName: { 
                required: true
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Any thoughts?  Oh, and I don't want to use knockout validation (for other reasons).

jquery 2.0, jquery ui 1.9.2, jquery validation 1.11.1, knockout 2.2.0

Comment: I think, when you "destroy" the dialog, the Validate Object are destroyed too, validate it using a `console.debug($('#product-form'));` (in chrome or using firebug in firefox) it will show the associated objects in the DOM element

Comment: Maybe `destroyOnClose: false` setting will solve your problem?

Comment: Unless `.on("dialogopen")` is not a valid method, there appears to be nothing wrong with your code.  Can you construct a jsFiddle demo?

Comment: Does the `.on("dialogopen"...` event handler fire when you expect it to?

Comment: When in the `.on("dialogopen"...` event handler, does the call to $('#product-form') find your form?

Comment: Yes, `.on("dialogopen...` is firing.  It seems as though the .validate() function leaves some residue behind even though the #product_form has been completely removed from the DOM.  I don't think the Validate Object is being destroyed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why exactly are you destroying and re-creating something that you only want to open->close->open->close->etc?

If jQuery Validation is working when it first opens, then *don't destroy it* since you're just going to need to use it again anyway.

```
destroyOnClose: false
```

And if you never destroy it, you will not have to call `.validate()` again, so you can get rid of this...

```
$("body").on("dialogopen", "#product-panel", function(event) { 
    $('#product-form').validate({...});
});
```

Comment: I ended up taking your advice and removed the custom `destroyOnClose` functionality.  My problem was that I had wrapped the knockout `dialog` with a `<!--ko with: variableName -->`, which caused a new dialog popup every time I updated `variableName`.  To fix the problem, I simply moved the `ko with` inside the dialog instead of outside. I still want to keep the answer "open", though, because I want to see if anyone knows how to reset the jQuery validate.

Comment: @eh1160, once initislized, there exists no method to "reset" jQuery Validate.